# Get values of different iteration - Jinja2

Tags: python, json, ansible, jinja2

i have this template in jinja:

```
{% for value in id_ip.results %}
    {
       "title": "asd",
       "rel":"adas",
       "type":"application/nalip+json",
       "href": "https://www.api.com:443/api/{{item.item.stdout}}/{{item.stdout}}"
    }{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The variables are being collected from a JSON list, wich come from an ansible task with 2 iterations:

```
- name: Define templatesssss
  template:
      src: requestpayload.j2
      dest: /tmp/requestpayload.j2
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644
   with_items:
      - "{{id_ip.results}}"
```

And `id_ip.results` have two iterations of this JSON.

```
  "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "var": "item"
        },
        "module_name": "debug"
    },
    "item": {
        "changed": true,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
            "warn": true
            },
            "module_name": "command"
        },
        "item": {
            "changed": true,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "warn": true
                },
                "module_name": "command"
            },
            "item": {
                "gateway": "1",
                "ip": "2"
            },
            "stdout": "62",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "62"
            ],
            "warnings": []
        },
        "stdout": "316",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "316"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
}
```

Im interested in the `stdout's` because is the value that i need to take in the template.
The result of the template is this:

```
  {
   "title": "asd",
   "rel":"adas",
   "type":"application/vnd.externalip+json",
   "href": "https://servicios.com:443/api/limits/2/externalnetworks/62/ips/316"
}        {
   "title": "asd",
   "rel":"adas",
   "type":"application/vnd.externalip+json",
   "href": "https://servicios.com:443/api/limits/2/externalnetworks/62/ips/316"
```

As you can see the values are **62** and **316** in both items, it would be fine if it were only one iteration but i need to pass the second iteration values to the second sector.

How can i do this?

Comment: Your JSON doesn't have a key `results` which you refer to, instead it has a syntax error - lingering comma in`"ip": "2",` How about you post a full, coherent, and verifiable example? If you don't care about it, why should anyone else care?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
% for value in id_ip.results %}
    {
       "title": "asd",
       "rel":"adas",
       "type":"application/nalip+json",
       "href": "https://www.api.com:443/api/{{value.item.item.stdout}}/{{value.item.stdout}}"
    }{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi  @Stijn Diependaele, if i use your solution, i got the next error: `"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'" `